# Wordpress WPML email from plugin

Tags: wordpress, email, wpml

I made a plugin myself with a user-interface part, but additionally a cronjob that sends out emails on a daily basis. The user-interface part works fine multilingual, but I don't get the email-function properly multilingual.

Email sending is separate activity and my customers do not have a wordpress website account. I register them in a dedicated table (customers)

What does it look like:

```
function send_email($customers) {
  foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    /*.... do something to set the correct language from $customer->mylanguage; ......
    $subject = __('This is the subject', 'wpml-text-file');
    $content = __('content of my email', 'wpml-text-file');
    $content .= __('second part of content of my email', 'wpml-text-file');
    $sendTo = $customer->email;
    $header = <...something.....>;
    wpmail($sendTo, $subject, $content, $header);
  }
}
```

I tried all solutions mentioned in the support documentation on https://wpml.org/documentation/support/sending-emails-with-wpml/ but unfortunately it did not work out.
E.g. this solution, since the customers are not registered:

```
add_filter(‘wpml_user_language’, ‘my_recipients_language’, 10, 2);
 
function my_recipient_language($lang, $email) {
  return get_language_from_my_database($email); // implement it in  your plugin/theme
}
```

I located this at the start of my loop, but nothing changed...

So please, give me some advice or a working example.

Comment: Finally I was able to make this feature work in the way I wanted. What did I change?
- added global $sitepress at the beginning of the function
- add $sitepress->switch_lang($customer->cust_language); in the line with points
And now it works fine.... Surprising no one came up with this solution.....